# Select row and next row that match condition

Tags: mysql

i have table `tiket_event` like this, it store all events happen by changing status on each ticket

| project_id | ticket_id | status | gmt_update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P01 | T01 | OPEN | 1620000488 |
| P01 | T01 | IN_PROGRESS | 1620000588 |
| P01 | T02 | OPEN | 1620000499 |
| P01 | T01 | DONE | 1620000688 |
| P01 | T02 | CLOSE | 1620000599 |
| P01 | T01 | CLOSE | 1620000788 |
| P02 | T03 | OPEN | 1650000788 |

what i want to do here is:

- group event by ticket_id
- order event in each group by gmt_update
- on each group, i will find event `IN_PROGRESS` then check whether one of next event is `DONE` or not. normally `DONE` will appear right after `IN_PROGRESS`. In abnormal case, other event can appear(eg: `IN_PROGRESS` -> `IN_TEST` -> `DONE`, i still count this case)
- count all of tikets that match these conditions, group by project_id

i suspect we can use this kind of syntax (just sample query i copy from internet)

```sql
select prev_word, word, next_word
from (
    select id, 
           lag(word) over (order by id) as prev_word,
           word,
           lead(word) over (order by id) as next_word
    from words
) as t
where word = 'name';
```

but i dont know how to put condition to select next row if status is `DONE`

---Edited---

Expected result i want to have

| project_id | count |
| --- | --- |
| P01 | 1 |
| P02 | 0 |

Could somebody help?

Thanks

Comment: Provide desired output for shown sample data. PS. The columns names in the query and in sample data does not match. Sync..

Comment: @Akina tks, i update expected result i want. the query in post just sample, i dont know how to write it on my case

Comment: Use one of my queries. Use `SELECT DISTINCT project_id` as base table and leftjoin my query as subquery.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```sql
-- IN_PROGRESS and DONE must be adjacent
WITH 
cte AS  ( SELECT ticket_id, 
                 status = 'IN_PROGRESS' AND LEAD(status) OVER (PARTITION BY ticket_id ORDER BY gmt_update) = 'DONE' normal
          FROM tiket_event )
SELECT ticket_id  -- or you need COUNT(ticket_id) ?
FROM cte
WHERE normal
```

or maybe (the task is not clear enough)

```sql
-- IN_PROGRESS and DONE must not be adjacent
SELECT DISTINCT ticket_id -- or COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id) ?
FROM tiket_event t1
JOIN tiket_event t2 USING (ticket_id)
WHERE t1.status = 'IN_PROGRESS'
  AND t2.status = 'DONE'
  AND t1.gmt_update < t2.gmt_update
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a79cd09d95fa7e1f9ec2182e8a50662

Comment: It's my downvote;; I object to the 'gate-keeping'. Either you think more information is required, or you don't

Comment: @Strawberry Sometimes it is more easy to get additional info while providing and adjusting partial solution. Anycase an answer for similar question is better than none answer i think.

Comment: I'm sure there are exceptions, but as a general principle, I disagree.